# Making a Google line chart from spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, html, google-sheets, charts

I have a very simple spreadsheet that looks like this: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1T8eNrLpk7bOuvHGDojsHALzoxHHHoQ6iJ7AZIAnZntE/edit?usp=sharing

How can I have a HTML line chart like the one in the code snippet, but that uses my spreadsheet as data? I want the dates as the X-axis and the weight as the Y-axis. It should look something like in the image.

[image]

I have tried to follow the tutorials on https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart but they are a bit too hard  for me.

```js
google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart', 'line']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawBasic);

function drawBasic() {

      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
      data.addColumn('number', 'X');
      data.addColumn('number', 'Dogs');

      data.addRows([
        [0, 0],   [1, 10],  [2, 23],  [3, 17],  [4, 18],  [5, 9],
        [6, 11],  [7, 27],  [8, 33],  [9, 40],  [10, 32], [11, 35],
        [12, 30], [13, 40], [14, 42], [15, 47], [16, 44], [17, 48],
        [18, 52], [19, 54], [20, 42], [21, 55], [22, 56], [23, 57],
        [24, 60], [25, 50], [26, 52], [27, 51], [28, 49], [29, 53],
        [30, 55], [31, 60], [32, 61], [33, 59], [34, 62], [35, 65],
        [36, 62], [37, 58], [38, 55], [39, 61], [40, 64], [41, 65],
        [42, 63], [43, 66], [44, 67], [45, 69], [46, 69], [47, 70],
        [48, 72], [49, 68], [50, 66], [51, 65], [52, 67], [53, 70],
        [54, 71], [55, 72], [56, 73], [57, 75], [58, 70], [59, 68],
        [60, 64], [61, 60], [62, 65], [63, 67], [64, 68], [65, 69],
        [66, 70], [67, 72], [68, 75], [69, 80]
      ]);

      var options = {
        hAxis: {
          title: 'Time'
        },
        vAxis: {
          title: 'Popularity'
        }
      };

      var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

      chart.draw(data, options);
    }
```

```html
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
  <div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reviewing Google Documentation on Charts and Line Charts in specific, I was able to create a conclusive snippet for you.

Firstly, find below all links I've searched to get to the conclusion:

- [Google Line Chart & Options](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart)
- [Loading Google Spreadsheets](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/spreadsheets)
- [Google Charts Query](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#Query)

The idea is to allow the library to parse the URL using a `Query` and give options to the `draw()` call. Using the response handler, we can retrieve the DataTable using `getDataTable`.

Since Stackoverflow has a strict CORS policy, follow [FiddleJS](https://jsfiddle.net/cs0e8akL/).

Comment: Wow, that's awesome! Thank you so much! How would I go about adding another line?

Comment: Just add an extra column as you did in the spreadsheet.

Comment: Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/q/69187201/1711950.